# How to achieve a bounded model in DynamoDB?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following use case:

In DynamoDB I want to hold a list of user events sorted in descending order, such that I see the latest events in the top. However I am only interested in the latest 1000 events.

At the moment I have a table with the userId as the Hash key, and the timestamp of the user events as range key.

Is there any efficient way to keep the number of items in the range for a given userId to a maximum of 1000, with the latest events first?

I am using the Java low-level API, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your table schema is perfect, you can query the table with userId and use option

```
ScanIndexForward => False
```

This will sort your data in descending order on range key (which is timestamp)

and you can use option

```
Limit => 1000
```

This will display latest 1000 events only.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, this answers how to get the latest 1000 events. But how do I keep the actual range to a maximum of 1000 events in the table itself? Such that I do not waste storage on events that I will never need again?

Comment: Then You have to add some mechanism to delete rows by yourself, their is no such method by default that i know :)

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to do this effectively? Does there exists any delete all before x, where x is a timestamp used as the range key.

Comment: I guess there are no inbuilt APIs for it, you manually have to identify your data that need to be flushed as you have hash+range, you have to supply exact values for both to delete that Item